# Eclipse CDT - how to quickly evaluate an expression which is not in the code?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have been away from Eclipse CDT for a while and have become spoiled by JetBrains' excellent IDEs (and the company won't let me have [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)). Admittedly these are mostly for interpreted, rather than compiled languages, so evaluation is simpler.

When I am breakpointed in Eclipse CDT, (how) can I quickly evaluate expressions involving variables known to the debugger, but in ways in which they are not used in the code?

For instance, if I have two integers, `i` and `j`, (how) can I quickly evaluate `i + j`?

Is it possible, given `char *s`, to evaluate `stlen(s)`? Or the result of a local function call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Off the top of my head I would suggest either the *Expression* view or the *Console* view, depending on what your flow is, etc.

### Expressions

The *Expressions* view allows you to add any arbitrary expressions to be evaluated by the selected frame every time the debugger hits a breakpoint or completes a single step.

The *Expressions* view is not open by default. You can open it from the *Window* -> *Show View* -> *Expressions*.

You can then press the *Add new expression* button and enter an expression to evaluate. (You can enter pretty much any expression:`i+j`, `strlen(s)`, or anything else you like)

Alternatively, you can:

1. from the context menu, select *Add watch expression...":

[image]

2. enter the expression in the pop-up:

[image]

3. the *Expressions* view will open and/or come to the top.

[image]

### Console

The console view allows you to enter GDB commands in standard [GDB syntax](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Syntax.html#Command-Syntax).

To use the Console:

1. Select the *gdb* item in the *Debug View*

[image]

2. The Console view will now display the interface to GDB:

[image]

3. Type commands to GDB, e.g. `print i + j` or `p i - j` (`p` is short for `print`):

[image]

**Other Hints when using the Console**

- You can "pin" the console so that it stays the selected console top with this button on the toolbar: [image]
- You can switch console with this drop-down:

[image]

- You can open a second console, e.g. one for GDB interaction and one for output of your program with this button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such an infromative response. I award you the answer and 50 bonus points for ushc a clear and helpful reply!

Comment: @Jonah. Nice explanation with screen shots.