# Force return with a specific value while debugging in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm debugging some C++ code in Eclipse configured with a MinGW gdb configuration.

When running gdb directly in a shell, I can return from a function immediately, and tell it what value the function should return, with for example `return 3`.

How do I do that while debugging in Eclipse rather than running gdb outside of Eclipse in a shell window?

Comment: Wasn't sure if with "terminal window" you were referring to the console I refer to in the answer I wrote. In case it didn't, or if a future reader comes along, I have attempted to give you a complete solution.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify; I wasn't aware of the gdb console!

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse CDT does not provide that feature in the UI with a button or similar. Feel free to enter a [feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT), or even better a [patch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing).

However, you can of type `return 3` in the GDB input console in CDT without having to leave the Eclipse environment. Here are some instructions I wrote for a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37367367/2796832) (but not duplicate) question that shows you how to use the console.

### Console

The console view allows you to enter GDB commands in standard [GDB syntax](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Syntax.html#Command-Syntax).

To use the Console:

1. Select the *gdb* item in the *Debug View*

[image]

2. The Console view will now display the interface to GDB:

[image]

3. Type commands to GDB, e.g. `print i + j` or `p i - j` (`p` is short for `print`):

[image]

**Other Hints when using the Console**

- You can "pin" the console so that it stays the selected console top with this button on the toolbar: [image]
- You can switch console with this drop-down:

[image]

- You can open a second console, e.g. one for GDB interaction and one for output of your program with this button:

[image]

Comment: That looks like it will work perfectly! I'll try it out when I'm back at work on Monday.